# blender file and obj file to join shapes - face mesh

Tags: mesh, objects, faces, blend-files

[image: character mesh/ head/eyes/lashes][image: base head]I am ***very*** new to blender, and quite frankly terrified by it! 
However(!), I am trying to recreate a couple of custom characters from DAI. A friend was kind enough to provide me with a blender file of the head meshes and, using Ninja ripper and nosesis, I ripped my character's face, eyes, and lashes mesh. I have tried to join shapes, but **nothing** happens!
I know I am missing a massively important step somewhere. I'm so sorry to be a pain but, Could anyone possible point me in the right direction please?

I added a screenshot just so people could see how far i've got with it/ what I was actually talking about

[image]

Comment: Could you be more speific about your project? What was meant "ripped"? What is Ninja ripper and nosesis? When "joining shapes" do you mean joining objects? (Object mode, Ctrl+J) Note that one must have one object of mesh type active (selected last) in order joining to work. If that's not what you're after please [edit] your post with more screenshots and some images; if possible upload blend here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ as well.

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much for getting back to me!!! 
Ninja ripper allowed me to 'rip' extract the meshes and textures straight from game so the gray face is the exact mesh of my character . 
Noesis allowed me to view the meshes and export them as obj files. I have also uploaded the blender file.
What I am trying to do is, morph the basehead into my character by 'Join shapes ' option. And although your reply did indeed work (thank you again btw) It morphed the meshes rather than the base head. I will also add more screenshots.

Comment: I don't see the link to the blender file, but what do you mean "morphed the meshes rather than the base head"? How do mesh differs from the base head? Join As Shapes works to active object so you get new shape key there. Also what is the grey object on the screenshot, is it only one face? It looks like object with edited face normals which makes it looks flat